# Change column names of numeric vector?

Tags: r, vector, names

Take `output<-matrix(sample(9),nrow=3,ncol=3)`. This gives me:

```
> output
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8    2    3
[2,]    4    7    6
[3,]    9    5    1
```

I want to change the column names to "a", "b", and "c". In other words, I want something like:

```
> output
       "a"  "b"  "c"
[1,]    8    2    3
[2,]    4    7    6
[3,]    9    5    1
```

There are many answers on this website about how to do this with a data frame, but what we have here believes itself to be an interger vector. So how can we handle it? I was surpised to find `names(output)[,c(1,2,3)]<-c("a","b","c")` run but apparently do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `colnames()`:

```
colnames(output) <- c("a","b","c")
```

Comment: This is surreal. Not only do I swear that I've already tried that, I've had the docs for colnames open in front of me this entire time. And yet, your solution works perfectly!

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but possibly you were not assigning to `colnames(output)` but instead `output <- colnames(c("a","b","c"))`? important part to remember is we only want to change the names of the columns and not assign the column names to output itself.

Comment: Also `dimnames(output)[[2]] = c("a", "b", "c")`